# Get non-repeating index from array fails on 0

Tags: javascript

I have the following function that returns a random non-repeating index from an array keeps pulling them out until all have been used and then resets itself and starts re-using them.

It also makes sure that the last one that was pulled out isn't the same as the next one pulled out on the reset so that you don't ever have the same index come out in a row.

```
var listIndexes = [];
var lastIndex;

function getRandomIndex(indexes)
{
    if (!listIndexes.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < indexes; i++) {
            listIndexes.push(i);
        }
    }

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * listIndexes.length);
    var uniqueIndex = listIndexes[randomIndex];

    listIndexes.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    if(lastIndex && uniqueIndex == lastIndex)
  {
    listIndexes = [];
    return getRandomIndex(indexes);
  }

  lastIndex = uniqueIndex;

  return uniqueIndex;
}

var index = getRandomIndex(5);

console.log(index);
```

However I've found that if the `lastIndex` and `uniqueIndex` both are `0`, then it returns it, so I get the index `0` returning in a row (regardless of the reset) which defeats the point of the conditional to prevent this.

Why is this happening? What is special about `0` that breaks the logic?

Comment: Haven't looked deeply enough to confirm, but I suspect the fact that `0` coerces to boolean `false` is to blame.

Comment: `lastIndex && uniqueIndex == lastIndex`  is falsy for `0` because it would be `0 && true` which will result in `0`. You most likely should use  `lastIndex !== undefined && uniqueIndex == lastIndex` instead.

Comment: @t.niese You should post that as an answer :) Works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lastIndex && uniqueIndex == lastIndex` is falsy for `0`  ([see MDN: Falsy for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Falsy)).

The given equation would be `0 && true` for `0`,  which will result in `0`.

You most likely should use `lastIndex !== undefined && uniqueIndex == lastIndex` instead. Because then you strictly compare if `lastIndex` as set or if it is still `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

try to do following

```
...
var lastIndex = -1; 

....

if(lastIndex>-1 && uniqueIndex == lastIndex)
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much of javascript. Maybe you have some problem with the splice method.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice

It says that it's used like that: list = list.slice(...); And maybe the other answer is part of the answer too. no se, good luck ;)